# When to use "and" operator in Ocaml AST

Tags: parsing, ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree

I am translating  the rules of my grammar into an AST.

Is it necessary to use the "and" operator in defining our AST?

For instance, I have translated my grammar thus far like so:

```
type program =
   |  Decls of typ * identifier * decls_prime

type typ =
   | INT
   | BOOL
   | VOID

type identifier = string

(* decls_prime = vdecl decls | fdecl decls *)
type declsprime =
   | Vdecl of variabledeclaration * decls
   | Fdecl of functiondeclaration * decls

(*“lparen” formals_opt “rparen” “LBRACE” vdecl_list stmt_list “RBRACE”*)
type functiondeclaration =
    | Fdecl of variabledeclarationlist * stmtlist

(*formals_opt = formal_list | epsilon *)
type FormalsOpt =
   |FormalsOpt of formallist

(* typ “ID” formal_list_prime *)
type formalList =
    | FormalList of typ * identifier * formallistprime

type formallistprime =
    | FormalListPrime of formalList

type variabledeclarationlist =
    | VdeclList of variabledeclaration * variabledeclarationlist

(*stmt stmt_list | epsilon*)
type stmtlist =
    | StmtList of stmt * stmtlist
    | StmtlistNil 

(* stmt = “RETURN” stmt_prime| expr SEMI |“LBRACE” stmt_list RBRACE| IF LPAREN expr RPAREN stmt stmt_prime_prime| FOR LPAREN expr_opt SEMI expr SEMI expr_opt RPAREN stmt| WHILE LPAREN expr RPAREN stmt*)
type Stmt
| Return of stmtprime
| Expression of expr
| StmtList of stmtlist
| IF of expr * stmt * stmtprimeprime
| FOR of expropt * expr * expropt * stmt 
| WHILE of expr * stmt

(*stmt_prime = SEMI| expr SEMI*)
type stmtprime
| SEMI 
| Expression of expr 

(*NOELSE | ELSE stmt*)
type stmtprimeprime
| NOELSE 
| ELSE of stmt

(* Expr_opt = expr | epsilon *)
type expropt =
| Expression of expr 
| ExprNil 

type Expr

type ExprPrime

(* Actuals_opt  = actuals_list  | epsilon *)
type ActualsOpt= 
| ActualsList of actualslist 
| ActualsNil

type ActualsList = 
| ActualsList of expr * actualslistprime

(*actualslistprime = COMMA expr actuals_list_prime | epsilon*)
type actualslistprime = 
| ActualsListPrime of expr * actualslistprime
| ALPNil
```

But it looks as though this example from Illinois uses a slightly different structure:

```
type program = Program of (class_decl list)
and class_decl = Class of id * id * (var_decl list) * (method_decl list)
and method_decl = Method....
```

Is it necessary to use "and" when defining my AST? And moreover, is it wrong for me to use a StmtList type rather than (stmt list) even though I call the AST StmtList method correctly in my parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need `and` when your definitions are mutually recursive. That is, if a statement could contain an expression and an expression could in turn contain a statement, then `Expr` and `Stmt` would have to be connected with an `and`. If your code compiles without `and`, you don't need the `and`.

PS: This is unrelated to your question, but I think it would make a lot more sense to use the `list` and `option` types than to define your own versions for specific types (such as `stmntlist`, `expropt` etc.). `stmtprime` is another such case: You could just define `Return` as `Return of expr option` and get rid of the `stmtprime` type. Same with `stmtprimeprime`.

Comment: I had to write the parser by hand (no parser generator) which is why I created StmtPrime, etc AST types. How would I define option? Very new to OCaml

Comment: @Matt I don't see why writing the parser by hand would affect what the AST looks like. "How would I define option?" `option` is a type from the standard library - you don't need to define it. You can just write `Return of stmt option` instead of `Return of stmtprime` and that's it.

Comment: But doesn't Stmt prime need to be built up? Because StmtPrime = Semi | Expression

Comment: so technically, its not optional?

Comment: @Matt I don't know what you mean by "built up" here. But just to be clear: My previous comment was a typo, it should of course be `Return of expr option`, not `stmt option`.

Comment: by built up, i mean stmtprime is a substructure of stmt, it needs to be built into a sub tree and passed to stmt so that the stmt subtree of AST can be built. In "Return of expr option" - are we making the semi optional?

Comment: @Matt I'm not following you. `stmtprime` is a type that you defined that could either contain an expression or nothing. `expr option` is also a type that could either contain an expression or nothing. Therefore these two types are completely interchangeable and the `stmtprime` type is unnecessary. Whether the semicolon is optional or not is a property of your parser, not your AST. The fact that you happened to name your no-expression constructor `SEMI` does not affect whether or not the parser expects a semicolon.

Comment: I understand now. thank you for your very patient and thorough explanation, I really appreciate it